# Do string resource XML files allow invalid Java variables as name attributes?

Tags: java, android, localization

The [Android developer docs for string resources](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html) show an example string which is also a valid Java variable ("hello_world") which it explains is accessed via `R.string.hello_world`

My question is whether the XML is permitted to contain string name attributes that are **invalid** as Java variables. For example, are the following string keys allowed as XML resource names, and if so, how would they be accessed via `R.string.<name>` in Java?

```
<string name="hello world" />

<string name="hello.world" />

<string name="42 hello world" />
```

Note to down-voters: **I am not attempting to actually do this**. I am attempting to understand what the file format allows and how the resources are converted.

Some context for what and why I'm asking:

My software converts key/value pairs to XML resources and automatically converts all keys to valid Java variables, so "hello-world" is converted to "hello_world". However a user reported that they wanted to **keep** "hello.world" as the value of XML name attribute. They informed me that the Android builder would convert it to "hello_world". So I am asking this question to  work out which cases I should automatically handle and which I should allow through.

Comment: The real question here is: "Why would you *want* to do that?"

Comment: I can clearly see that it is not good practice. You've jumped to a conclusion that want to achieve is wrong. I've updated my question with some context as to what I actually am trying to achieve.

Comment: I suppose you might still be missing some context. What does your user have to do with xml attributes? Is it a user of an app, or a library?

Comment: It is an app - a file format converter. The XML attribute I refer to is the "name" attribute in the string element `<string name="..">` I incorrectly typed "key" in my question, which I've now fixed

Comment: Now it makes more sense. Your XML attributes can contain any valid UTF-8 if escaped properly. Now, if your users take that xml and try to use it as strings.xml, then the Android builder will cough or have some fun with it. There's just no way around that.

Comment: This was my initial thinking, but the reporter of this "bug" claims they are using "." symbols in their string names quite happily.

Comment: The reporter may not understand java too well then... maybe those are static finals on static classes... Just like the two dots in `R.layout.abc`

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. Xml files are parsed and the static class R is generated and, in order to compile, the class has to contain valid members name.

Comment: I was informed by a user of my software that "x.y" would automatically be converted to "x_y". Are they wrong?

Comment: After installing Android Studio and building the examples above, I can confirm that the "." in the dot-separated key is converted to an underscore in the resultant Java class. ·Perhaps a feature of Android Studio, but either way, their claim was not wrong.

Comment: No, it is not AndroidStudio. Is probably ADT that takes care of this sort of conversion. Still space in the key, or key starting with a number leads to a compile time error

Comment: yes it seems to be a one-off conversion. I've not been able to identify any others. The conversion can also result in a key collision, which makes it an exceptionally annoying "feature"

Comment: yes in case for instance you declare my_key and my.key

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question because although the advice here about best practice is valid, it was not best practice that I asked about.

The answer is that although the string named "hello.world" **would be** an invalid Java variable, it is permitted in the XML as the build process automatically converts the `"."` symbol to an *underscore* before it becomes a Java class member variable.

The following strings:

```
<string name="foo_bar"> .. </string>
<string name="foo.baz"> .. </string>
```

Will produce (**whether due to a feature or a bug**) members in R.java as follows:

```
public static final class string {
    public static final int foo_bar=0x7f0a000f; // <- valid
    public static final int foo_baz=0x7f0a0010; // <- valid (CONVERTED)
}
```

The following two strings however:

```
<string name="foo_bar"> .. </string>
<string name="foo.bar"> .. </string>
```

Will result in a **collision** and the build process will fail:

```
public static final class string {
    public static final int foo_bar=0x7f0a000f; // <- valid
    public static final int foo_bar=0x7f0a0010; // <- DUPLICATE
}
```

The following strings:

```
<string name="foo bar"> .. </string>
<string name="foo-baz"> .. </string>
<string name="42foo"> .. </string>
```

Will break the build process producing invalid members in R.java as follows:

```
public static final class string {
    public static final int 42foo=0x7f0a0000;   // <- invalid
    public static final int foo bar=0x7f0a000f; // <- invalid
    public static final int foo-baz=0x7f0a0010; // <- invalid
}
```

I verified these by building a project via Android Studio and also via the command line Gradle program. The `"." => "_"` conversion appears to be a one-off (although I only tried a few common punctuations as shown above.

---

TL;DR
**Names should be valid Java variables, but the XML format and build process will automatically convert "." symbols adding the risk of key collisions.**