# Using dots in xml ids

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

this is my first question

**In Java I have never had this problem before.**

I spent two days because I had an issue **just on design mode** on Android studio inflating a CustomView with **kotlin**. I had a findByView = null after the inflate. Running the app, all is right

```
View.inflate(context, R.layout.widget_navigation_section_button, this) 
mLabel = findViewById(R.id.navigation_section_title)
mLabel.setText("something")
```

That throws a NPE *(for real in kotlin: kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.widget.TextView   at ... $mLabel$2.invoke(CustomView.kt:22))*

Normally, I use a `<layout>[.<where_container>].<name>` pattern to name ids and string on XMls (ex: `android:id="@+id/main.description_container.title"`)
This is translated automatically in `R.id.main_description_container_title`(notice dots become underscores) in code

The issue was solved when I replace these dots with underscores manually in the XML

I was looking for name conventions explaining why dots should not used in ids or string naming, but without success. I want to know what is the real issue with this name convention. This should be really avoid it ?

Should I just drop the idea and just user underscores ? Looking at it is an issue just on kotlin, maybe some gradle configuration ther ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I found this answer pointing to more o less the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24140877/do-string-resource-xml-files-allow-invalid-java-variables-as-name-attributes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use dots, because following expression `R.id.main.description_container.title` will try to find member `main` which has type `Int` and then try find property `description_container`, but `Int` doesn't have such property

Comment: Ok, but when you launch the app, It works perfect. This is an issue just Android Studio's design preview mode + kotlin. With Java It works too

Comment: @cgarrido I think, it's bad idea to use dots, but you are welcome to open bug report (anyway, Kotlin isn't officially supported)